# sh include & in the command

Tags: shell, yaml, sh

```
 M00973914:ecr-token-refresh aruj$ sh -c "ping google.com &; sleep 10;echo Done waiting; exit 0;"
```

I tried several different ways to include & in the command and have the ping run in the background. 
Finally I need to include the command in  a YAML file. `\\u00026 is what I got from a yaml converter but that doesn't seem to work either

The line would appear in a yaml file as

```
"command": ["sh","-c","/bin/ecr-token-refresh &; sleep 100;echo Done waiting; exit 0;"],
```

Comment: `&;` is invalid syntax. Both `&` and `;` are command separators -- you can use one or the other but not both, just like it's a syntax error to write `echo hello ; ; echo world`.

Comment: Beyond that -- YAML isn't natively a language that has anything to do with bash. If you're trying to represent a shell script in a YAML config file, you'll need to provide some actual details about how it's being represented, by which software it's parsed, etc.